# Gradient on the background of the page

Tags: jquery, css

I'm learning to code and I come to you with a question.
I wonder how the bubble following the cursor on this [page](https://www.poppr.be/en)  is built.
I'm particularly interested in its "waving/throbbing".

I can only create a plain gradient that follows the cursor.

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {

    windowWidth = $(window).width();
    windowHeight = $(window).height();
    
    mouseXpercentage = Math.round(event.pageX / windowWidth * 100);
    mouseYpercentage = Math.round(event.pageY / windowHeight * 100);
    
    $('.radial-gradient').css('background', 'radial-gradient(at ' + mouseXpercentage + '% ' + mouseYpercentage + '%, #3498db, #202020)');
    
  });
```

```css
body{
background-color: black;
}
.radial-gradient {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: #202020;
    background: 
      radial-gradient(
       at center, #3498db, #202020
      );
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='radial-gradient'>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. After that edit your question to meet those guidelines and include a [repro] for debugging details. Last but not least, flag your question accordingly. In your case, you do not use vanilla JS but jQuery.

Comment: @tacoshy is it good now?

Comment: include a HTML, then move all the code to a working snippet (`Ctrl + M`or the `<>` button). Then state where you actually stuck. Note, that asking for recommendations for libraries, tools, etc is off-topic at SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really cool idea to learn by reverse-engineering stuff you like!

I don't want so say it's impossible to recreate that effect with plain css and jQuery, but by investigating the page's html, I can tell you that they're using [three.js](https://threejs.org) in a canvas element:

[image: screenshot of the page's html]

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help, I'm going to study. :)